# doubt in implementing agreement score

Tags: agreement-statistics

I am trying to implement the agreement score illustrated [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2488396/). In particular, Equation 1 states that the contribution of sample $i$ to the agreement score of rater $j$ is

$$
\hat{s}_{ij} = \frac{n_{i, g_{ij}} - 1}{(\sum_{g=1}^3n_{i, g}) - 1}
$$

where $n_{i,g}$ is the observed number of raters giving grade $g$ to sample $i$. In addition, $g_{i,j}$ is the observed grade assigned to sample $i$ by rater $j$, but $n_{i, g_{ij}}$ is not defined. What could be the correct formulation?

The agreement score for rater $j$ is then estimated as

$$
\hat{s}_{j} = \frac{1}{N_j}\sum_{i=1}^m\hat{s}_{ij}
$$

where $m$ is the number of samples.

Answer (score 0):

$n_{i,g_{ij}}-1$ is the number of raters who assigned the same grade (namely $g_{ij}$) to the sample $i$ as rater $j$. $n_{i,g_{ij}}$ is then the number of raters who assigned the same grade to the sample $i$ as rater $j$ including rater $j$.